# BERT error while calling a custom function with Application.Run VBA "The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

Tags: c#, r, excel, vba, vsto

I'm actually using VSTO c# to build an Addin that uses BERT has a bridge to get custom R functions on excel. But Im getting some errors trying to call custom functions on Bert functions directory using Application.Run in VBA

Actually I have on ThisAddin class:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void InternalStartup()
    {
    }

    public void BertCall(string functionName, String dataRange)
    {
        if(dataRange.Equals("00:00"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Blank cells were found, pleace fill it and try again");
        }
        else
        {
            double result = Application.Run("BERT.Call", functionName, getCurrentWorkSheet().Range[dataRange]);
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
        }
    }

    private Worksheet getCurrentWorkSheet()
    {
        Worksheet currentWorksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(
        this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
        return currentWorksheet;
    }
```

And in another class Called BertCalls I have the following code

```
    Validations validate = new Validations();

    public void bertCalls(string functionName)
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.BertCall(functionName, validate.getRange()); //this method calls ThisAddIn BertCall method, that handles the comunication with Bert
    }

    public void Sumar()

    {
        Excel.Range selectedRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
        bertCalls("sum");

    }
```

As you see Im using some custom validation classes.

Actually it is working fine when I call build-in R functions, like "sum" but when I try to call custom functions I had the compile error while excecuting the method "Can't execute the macro or it is disabled"

I did the following things:

- Create the functions on Documents/Bert2/functions
- Tried to call by the name of the custom function using BERT.Call paramether, but does not work.
- Enabling Trust center to VBA applications and macros
- Change the Application.Run param same as in BERT documentation to 
  ***Application.Run(functionName, getCurrentWorkSheet().Range[dataRange]);*** where functionName is the name of the customFunction, and called by R.AddTest, but get a big negative number.

I need to execute custom functions using BERT with VBA, but I'm getting this error, and I did not find nothing to avoid this error.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

I was using windows 10, in onedrive/documents carpet route where BERT2 and the custom R functions, I had to copy that carpet in the local document carpet  C:\Users\user\Documents and it works with the exact code above.

Take care of the routes if you need to work with documents route in windows 10. OneDrive/Documents != User/Documents